# Trying to find components of values and code 0/1 in a new variable

Tags: r

I did not find anything similar and hope you can help me. I have a dataset which looks like attached. (data1)

data1

[image]

Now, I want to code all rows containing specific words in the variable "Title", for example "book", "paper" and "confetti", with a 1 in a new variable, and the others with a 0. (data2)

data2

[image]

I would be thankful for any advice!

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Oh sorry I will take care of this next time! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grepl` try :

```
data2 <- transform(data1, 
          exclude = as.integer(grepl('\\b(book|paper|confetti)\\b', Title)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The tidyverse method :

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data <- tibble(title = c("This is a book", "This is an article", "This is nothing", "This is another article"),
              value = 2001:2004)

my_data %>% 
 mutate(exclude = ifelse(title %>% str_detect("book|article"), 1, 0))
```